# display two different forms using value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to display form 1 if drop down value selected is one and similarly display form 2 if drop down value selected is two .

I am using JS to do this. Here is the code .please HELP ME.

I am not aware of JQuery so please help me from basics if the solution is in JQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--
    To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
    To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
    and open the template in the editor.
    -->
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset_sim.css">
            <script>
                $('p select[name=asset_sim]').change(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == 'asset') {
                        $('#asset_form').show();
                    } else {
                        $('#sim_form').show();
                    }
                });


                $('p select[name=asset_sim]').change(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == 'sim') {
                        $('#sim_form').show();
                    } else {
                        $('#asset_form').hide();
                    }
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <?php
            include 'header.php';
            include 'footer.php';
            include 'config.php';
            //
            //if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
            //    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'User_name');
            //    $fullname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Full_name');
            //    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
            //    $roll = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'role');
            //    $contact = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'contact_no');
            //
            //
            //    if (($sql = $conn->prepare("insert into tmtool.user_master (Username,Full_name,Email,Role,Contact_no)"
            //            . "values (?,?,?,?,?)")) == FALSE) {
            //        echo "false";
            //    }
            //    $sql->bind_param('sssss', $username, $fullname, $email, $roll, $contact);
            //
            //    // 2nd query for execution
            //
            //    if (($sql1 = $conn->prepare("insert into tmtool.login (Username,Password) values (?,?)")) == FALSE) {
            //        echo "false";
            //    }
            //    $sql1->bind_param('ss', $username, $tmppass);
            //


    //inserting userdetails into database
            }
            ?>



            <div id="page-wrapper">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">Assets and SIM Management</h1>
                    </div> 
                </div>




                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <label>Enter Asset Details</label>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <p>Asset or Sim details :
        <select name="asset_sim" required="required">
            <option value="">-- Select an Option --</option>
            <option value="asset">Enter Asset Details</option>
            <option value="sim">Enter SIM Details</option>

        </select>
    </p>

    <div  class="dataTable_wrapper">
          <div id="asset_form">  
        <form   action="AssetMaster.php" method="POST" role="form">


                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Device Name</label>
                        <select name="device_name">

<option>Laptop</option>
<option>Mobile</option>
<option>Data Card</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>




                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Company name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="company_name" type="text" id="company_name" required="required" placeholder="Enetr Company name" title="Please Enetr company name of Device">
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Model Number</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="Model_number"  type="text" id="model_number" required="required" placeholder="Enetr Model number" title="Enter model number of Your Device ">
                    </div>



                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>OS version</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="OS_version"  required="required"  id="Os-versionid" placeholder="Enter OS version detail" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Enter OS version details')" onchange="try {
        setCustomValidity('')
    } catch (e) {
    }"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="sub" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Submit</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
                </div>  

        </form>  
              </div> 

    </div>


    <div  class="dataTable_wrapper">
          <div id="sim_form">
        <form   action="AssetMaster.php" method="POST" role="form">


                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Type</label>
                        <select name="sim_type">
<option>Prepaid</option>
<option>Postpaid</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Simcard Number</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="simcard_no" type="text" id="simcard_name" required="required" placeholder="Enetr Simcard Number" title="Please Enter Simcard Number">
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Service Provider</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="service_provider"  type="text" id="service_provider" required="required" placeholder="Enter Service provider name" title="Enter Service provider name ">
                    </div>




                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="sub" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Submit</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
                </div>  

        </form>
                  </div> 


    </div>
</div>

                        </div>


                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div>

            <!-- jQuery -->
            <!--<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>-->

            <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
            <!--<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->

            <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
            <script src="../../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

            <!-- DataTables JavaScript -->
            <script src="../../bower_components/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../../bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
            <script src="../../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

            <!-- Page-Level Demo Scripts - Tables - Use for reference -->
            <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
        responsive: true
    });
});
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Some comments, please clean up the code, there is a lot of unnecessary information. Secondly the code above the html will not work for the html below, because the jquery has been executed before the html is written. So either you put it below the html or you add $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: Thank you it is working . But now if I want to store the same data in database then how would i differentiate which data is of which form...

Comment: In @Alekos answer you can see that the submit button has two different values. When submitting that data will also be send to the server. So you can see which form is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can see a working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var selector = $("#form_selector");
    
    var last = null;
    
    function update(){
        var selected = selector.val();

        if (last)
            $("#form_" + last).css('display', 'none');
        
        $("#form_" + selected).css('display', 'block');
        last = selected;
    }
    
    update();
    
    selector.on("change", update);
});
```

```css
form {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="form_selector">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<hr>

<form name="form" id="form_1">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your Username"></input><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form 1"></input><br>
</form>
    
<form name="form" id="form_2">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email"></input><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form 2"></input><br>
</form>
```